# At what speeds does time dilations start to occur?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, speed-of-light

My question is, is it possible for time dilation to occur at a speed less than that of speed of light?

Comment: It always occurs at speeds less than that of light

Comment: So it occurs at all speeds greater than Zero? or is there any specific speed range or value that the time dilations can start to be noticed?

Comment: any speed between zero and $c$

Comment: What you need to define is what you mean by "start to be noticed". As with all things scale matters. If you're doing an experiment with $10^{-10}$ fractional time sensitivity then you can notice time dilation at speeds much lower than if your experiment only has $10^{-4}$ fractional time sensitivity.

Comment: More specifically, "start to be noticed" depends very much on the precision of your measuring device.  There's a huge gap between "my measuring device is an optical lattice clock" and "my measuring device is noticing that my twin's hair is more/less gray than mine."

Answer (score 1):

The time dilation relative to a stationary observer is given by:

$$ \frac{d\tau}{dt} = \sqrt{1 - \frac{v^2}{c^2}} $$

where $d\tau/dt$ is the ratio of the elapsed time on the moving object to the elapsed time for the stationary observer. For any value of $v$ greater than zero the ratio $d\tau/dt \lt 1$ meaning there is some time dilation though in practice it may be too small to measure.

The example that springs to mind of low velocity time dilation is for GPS satellites. The time dilation of a GPS satellite is partly due to gravitational time dilation but also partly due to its relative velocity of about 14000 km/hour. Although that speed is high by everyday standards it is only $0.000013c$, so by light standards it's hardly moving. Nevertheless the time dilation is easily measurable.

The [Hafele-Keating experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hafele%E2%80%93Keating_experiment) measured time dilation by flying clocks in airplanes. As with the GPS satellites there were both gravitational and kinetic contributions to the time dilation, but these could be teased be teased apart and the kinetic time dilation measured to an accuracy of about 10% even though the speed were only a few hundred miles per hour.

Comment: The Wikipedia article you linked to provides a breakdown of the general-relativistic & special-relativistic effects.  Note that the special-relativistic effects are different for the two flights because they're being compared to a clock on the Earth's surface, which is itself moving due to Earth's rotation.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert: oh yes, thanks, I managed to miss that on a quick skim through. I'll update my answer.